# need help in adding objects to array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am fetching data from a text file and need help in making the information into an object..

Array:

```
['celestine,timmy,celestinetimmy93@gmail.com,repeat 124\narun,mohan,reach@gmail.com,repeat 124213\njobi,mec,mec@gmail.com,rave\njalal,muhammed,jallu@gmail.com,rave1231212321\nvineeth,mohan,get,rave1231212321\n' ]
```

I need the values till \n in one object

expected result:

```
    [{'celestine,timmy,celestinetimmy93@gmail.com,repeat 124}
                                              {arun,mohan,reach@gmail.com,repeat 124213}

{jalal,muhammed,jallu@gmail.com,rave1231212321}
                                                 {vineeth,mohan,get,rave1231212321} ]
```

Comment: use regular expressions.

Comment: Did you try anything on your own?

Comment: You should just look at split and replace functions.

Comment: expected output is not meet to any standard.Its illegal and wrong format of array object

Answer (score 1):

In order to create an object, you'll need to format the string inside the curly braces as a dictionary of key value pairs. I am not sure what the keys or values are in your case. However if I assume that the key is "key" and the value is the text then:

```
var txt = 'celestine,timmy,celestinetimmy93@gmail.com,repeat 124\narun,mohan,reach@gmail.com,repeat 124213\njobi,mec,mec@gmail.com,rave\njalal,muhammed,jallu@gmail.com,rave1231212321\nvineeth,mohan,get,rave1231212321\n';

// Use trim, to remove the trailing whitespace, in your case a '\n'
// Use split to convert the text into an array of elements
var arr = txt.trim().split('\n');

// Use the map function to map each string to an object
var objects = arr.map(function(element) {
              return { key: element};
          });
```

Here is the output:

```
objects = [ { key: 'celestine,timmy,celestinetimmy93@gmail.com,repeat 124' },
  { key: 'arun,mohan,reach@gmail.com,repeat 124213' },
  { key: 'jobi,mec,mec@gmail.com,rave' },
  { key: 'jalal,muhammed,jallu@gmail.com,rave1231212321' },
  { key: 'vineeth,mohan,get,rave1231212321' } ]
```

Comment: ```
var txt = 'celestine,timmy,celestinetimmy93@gmail.com,repeat 124\narun,mohan,reach@gmail.com,repeat 124213\njobi,mec,mec@gmail.com,rave\njalal,muhammed,jallu@gmail.com,rave1231212321\nvineeth,mohan,get,rave1231212321\n';

// Use trim, to remove the trailing whitespace, in your case a '\n'
// Use split to convert the text into an array of elements
var arr = txt.trim().split('\n');

// Use the map function to map each string to an object
var objects = arr.map(function(element) {
              return element;
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do in this way.

after applying splitting   by **'\n'**

```
 ['celestine,timmy,celestinetimmy93@gmail.com,repeat
 124\narun,mohan,reach@gmail.com,repeat
  124213\njobi,mec,mec@gmail.com,rave\njalal,muhammed,jallu@gmail.com,rave1231212321\nvineeth,mohan,get,rave1231212321\n'
 ]
```

you will get single one dimensional array.

```
["celestine,timmy,celestinetimmy93@gmail.com,repeat 124", "arun,mohan,reach@gmail.com,repeat 124213", "jobi,mec,mec@gmail.com,rave", "jalal,muhammed,jallu@gmail.com,rave1231212321", "vineeth,mohan,get,rave1231212321", ""]
```

Then looping it to get each individual record.

JS :

```
var test = ['celestine,timmy,celestinetimmy93@gmail.com,repeat 124\narun,mohan,reach@gmail.com,repeat 124213\njobi,mec,mec@gmail.com,rave\njalal,muhammed,jallu@gmail.com,rave1231212321\nvineeth,mohan,get,rave1231212321\n' ]
var arrString = [];
test.forEach(function(val,key){  
        arrString = val.split('\n')
        });
console.log(arrString);
arrString.forEach(function(val,key){
    console.log(val.split(','));
})
```

Answer (score -1):

try this idea.

```
var x = "celestine,timmy,celestinetimmy93@gmail.com,repeat 124\narun,mohan,reach@gmail.com,repeat 124213\njobi,mec,mec@gmail.com,rave\njalal,muhammed,jallu@gmail.com,rave1231212321\nvineeth,mohan,get,rave1231212321\n";
   var y = x.split("\n");
```

implement the remaining part. convert the  array of arrays into array of objects using loops

Comment: Surprisingly -ve vote what is the reason bro. explian it